# Creating a Bash Script to Check and Disable SE Linux: How to Prompt User Input?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, selinux

How do I create a bash script that prompts the user to check if SE Linux is enabled on their machine, and if it is, requests them to execute a script to disable it?

Comment: The world is your oyster! Go for it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
ENABLED=`cat /selinux/enforce`
if [ "$ENABLED" == 1 ]; then
  echo "SELinux is enabled, disable? (yes/no):"
  read disable
  if [ $disable == "yes" ]; then
    echo "disabling selinux"
    setenforce 0
  fi
fi
```

This script should be run as root, or with permission to do the following:

```
cat /selinux/enforce
setenforce 0
```

Comment: /selinux/enforce does not exist. You should use the command "getenforce" to check the current selinux status.

Answer (score 0):

To correct the accepted answer.

a) Use "getenforce" as below to do your scripting

```
SELINUX_STATE=$(getenforce)
if [ "$SELINUX_STATE" == "Enforcing" ]; then
  echo "SELinux is enabled"
elif [ "$SELINUX_STATE" == "Permissive" ]; then
  echo "SELinux is permissive"
else 
  echo "SELinux is disabled (or missing)"
fi
```

b) `setenforce 0` sets selinux into permissive mode - which is not the same as disabled. The only way to disable is to edit the config and restart.

```
sudo sed -c -i "s/\SELINUX=.*/SELINUX=disabled/" /etc/sysconfig/selinux
sudo restart
```